# Properties button disabled when accessing network properties through IContextMenu

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7-x64

So, I have a c++ plugin dll for an app that supports plugins. The dll enumerates the Shell Folder for networks and displays your networks. It then allows you to invoke action on default Context Menu actions for those networks.

Now, if you invoke the action for say "Local Area Connection", it is the same as right-clicking on it and going to properties. However, the difference when I do it manually vs launching it through the app, is that the properties button for IPv4 and IPv6 properties is disabled. Which makes me wonder if it has something to do with permissions, but I have UAC set to lowest and I start the app with Admin privileges. I also added a manifest to the dll with admin permissions. Neither of these changes made any difference.

The action on the context menu is being called using InvokeCommand() of IContextMenu.

Any ideas?